# app_context_processor occurs object is not callable in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

hi i'm new to flask and i have a question.

I've made `template_functions.py` for using functions in template of blueprint like below :

template_functions.py :

```
@my_bp.app_context_processor
def get_today_date():
    return str(datetime.date.today())
```

`__init__.py` of blueprint app :

```
my_bp = Blueprint(~~~~)
from template_functions.py import *
```

`test.html`

```
{{ get_today_date }}
```

but application occurs an `object is not callable error` when i registered get_today_date as an app context processor

i've changed `@my_bp.app_context_processor` to `@my_bp.context_processor`, but anything is happened. how can i use them ?

Comment: where is your main app(`app=Flask(~~~)`) defined? Did you register the blueprint `my_bp` to the main app?

Comment: @AshokaLella sure, blueprint works well without app_context_prosessor

Comment: @AshokaLella All of thing of my application is working well, the only problem is app_context_processor does not work well

Answer (score 0):

From the flask docs

> A context processor is a function that returns a dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged with the template context, for all templates in the app (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/)

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user():
    return dict(user=g.user)
```

So in your case replace your get_today_date() with this

```
@my_bp.app_context_processor
def get_today_date():
   return dict(dtandtime=datetime.date.today())
```

and now in your template, you will be able to call {{dtandtime}}